# Gemfile.lock write error, permissions?

Tags: ruby, linux, bundler

I created a Rails model "model" a while ago and now I'm trying to run the server.  After a `bundle install` I get:

> There was an error while trying to write to Gemfile.lock. It is likely that  you need to allow write permissions for the file at path: `/home/thiago/model/Gemfile.lock`

Tried `rails s` to see what happens and:

```
/home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:235:in `rescue in lock': There was an error while trying to write to Gemfile.lock. It is likely that  (Bundler::InstallError)
you need to allow write permissions for the file at path: 
/home/thiago/model/Gemfile.lock
  from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:220:in `lock'
  from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:34:in `lock'
  from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:43:in `setup'
  from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
  from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.1/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:79:in `setup'
  from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.1/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:91:in `'
  from /home/thiago/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
  from /home/thiago/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
  from /home/thiago/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
  from /home/thiago/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:9:in `'
```

Can I set the permissions for the Gemfile.lock so I can bundle and run server?

```
$ ls -a -l
total 80
drwxr-xr-x. 13 root   root   4096 May 19 14:08 .
drwx------. 41 thiago thiago 4096 Jul  7 23:51 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  8 root   root   4096 May 19 14:08 app
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root   root   4096 May 19 14:08 config
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root    155 May 19 14:08 config.ru
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 May 19 14:08 db
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 May 19 14:08 doc
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root    765 May 19 14:08 Gemfile
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root    430 May 19 14:08 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root   root   4096 May 19 14:08 lib
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 May 19 14:08 log
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 May 19 14:08 public
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root    270 May 19 14:08 Rakefile
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root   9208 May 19 14:08 README.rdoc
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 May 19 14:08 script
drwxr-xr-x.  7 root   root   4096 May 19 14:08 test
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root   root   4096 May 19 14:08 tmp
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root   root   4096 May 19 14:08 vendor
```

Model files created incorrectly?

Comment: Well, what are the current permissions for the file in question?

Comment: It looks look you've created the app as root. chown all the files to yourself and you should be ok

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Your app root directory (whose permissions govern file creation) and files are all owned by root instead of your user (possibly because you did `sudo rails new`—don’t use `sudo` for that). You can change the permissions by doing:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) myappfolder
```

Where “myappfolder” is your Rails app’s root directory.

By the way, a good tip with regard to `sudo` is to always try the command without it first, then, if there’s a permissions error when it runs, you may need `sudo`. Don’t default to using `sudo`.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes the above answer:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) myappfolder
```

will give you the error:

```
chown: ifeegoo: illegal group name
```

You can also try this kind of command:

```
sudo chown -R ifeegoo: /Users/ifeegoo/workspace/rails/Test
```

Comment: Essentially: `sudo chown -R $(whoami): myappfolder`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, that's how i fixed mine.

If you are using **ZSH** then goto

> profile -> command

and check "Run command as a login shell" and close the terminal.
Fire up your terminal and initiate `bundle install` command.