# Web application could not be started redmine3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redmine

I am getting different error
Web application could not be started

```
Web application could not be started
There was an error while trying to write to Gemfile.lock. It is likely that

you need to allow write permissions for the file at path:
/usr/share/redmine/Gemfile.lock (Bundler::InstallError)
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:235:in rescue in lock' /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:220:inlock’
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/environment.rb:34:in lock' /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:43:insetup’
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:120:in setup' /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/setup.rb:17:in<top (required)>’
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in require' /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:inrequire’
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:245:in block in run_load_path_setup_code' /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:348:inrunning_bundler’
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:243:in run_load_path_setup_code' /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:inpreload_app’
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in <module:App>' /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:inmodule:PhusionPassenger’
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `’
```

Comment: You probably used `apt` to install RoR. Don't do this: http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

Before starting Redmine, you need to install the necessary gems. For that, navigate to the directory where the `Gemfile` resides and run `bundle install`. In your case, this is:

```
cd /usr/share/redmine
bundle install
```

Be sure to run this as a user with write permissions in the directory. If this is only root, you can run `sudo bundle install` in that directory instead.

You have to repeat this every time the `Gemfile` is changed, usually after each new code deployment.

Answer (score -1):

The solution for your issues can be found in the below link

[Gemfile.lock write error, permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519090/gemfile-lock-write-error-permissions)

In your terminal do

```
   $whoami
```

the output from the above command has to used to give the write permissions to folder and files.In your terminal do

```
  cd /usr/shared

  sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) redmine/
```

If it is not the username issue, try the below

```
    sudo  chmod  -R 777  redmine/
```

Comment: Recursively setting all files to `777` is a incredibly bad advice. This removes *any* security guarantees on the server and is likely to lead to remote-code-execution vulnerabilities in the deployed web app.

Comment: @HolgerJust, thank you for pointing the danger of using 777 recursively.

Comment: Sir,i changed the permission but after restarting apache i am getting this error 
 Web application could not be started
undefined method `require_sudo_mode' for EmailAddressesController:Class (NoMethodError)
  /usr/share/redmine/app/controllers/email_addresses_controller.rb:21:in `<class:EmailAddressesController>'
  /usr/share/redmine/app/controllers/email_addresses_controller.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block